# How to correctly import bootstrap scss in an angular project to avoid duplicated styles?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

How do you set up an angular project so that you can use bootstrap's mixins and variables without importing the styles over and over again in every component you need them in every page? The project I'm working on currently does this (and uses angular router to serve pages) and it results in importing the variables.scss multiple times which seems like a big performance issue to me:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by importing a scss file that contains some styles in multiple components. You should only import the styles in your root scss file, don't import these files in your component scss. The only files I would recommend importing in your component scss is the functions, variables, and mixins. You can use those scss functions to create dynamic styles.

Comment: When you say, "I would recommend importing in your component scss is the functions, variables, and mixins" doesn't this mean that these files could then be imported multiple times on a page if multiple components use those functions/variables? Ideally I'd like to import the variables once globally and have all components be able to use those variables. Does that make sense?

Comment: these files only contain scss functions. You can reference these functions in your components without creating duplicates.

Comment: To add to this a bit more, typically scss lib should contain three types of files, functions which can be used inside a style, but don't have any style types defined,  variables which as there name suggest have commonly used variables, and then the scss files that have the actual styles definitions and probably use the two files stated. this way you can import your func and var files as many times as you need without worry of duplication. if you import the style files, you will create duplicates.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Since functions, mixins, and variables aren't real styles that actually generate css, they are compiled away and only actual styles that used them remain, right?